# Save an arraylist with sharedpreferences and show it in listview

Tags: java, android

I have two activities. I want to get edittext data from Note.java and put it in listview from MainActivity.java.
But I couldn't do it in list format.

**Note.java**

```
  public class Note extends FragmentActivity implements


EditText editText,editText2;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);



    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);



SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("note", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

        editor.putString("myKey", editText.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
  }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

ListView listView;
List list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

  SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("note", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String baslik = sharedPref.getString("myKey",null);

    list = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    list.add(baslik);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: Hi Elbis, welcome to StackOverflow! You have to explain better what's going on with your code, your app is crasing or getting an error? post the error log. I see you're trying to solve your problem with SharedPreferences, is that necessary or you just don't know exactly how to do it?

Comment: Thank you @Shermano. I'm not getting an error but app is crashing. SharedPreferences not necessary. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`SharedPreferences` can store only primitive data types.you can not store References types in `SharedPreferences`.for this case I use `Gson` library.

**Step 1**: Convert list to String

```
Gson g = new Gson();
String str  = g.toJson(list);
```

**Step 2**: Store String in `SharedPreferences`

for getting data from `SharedPreferences` you must deserialize your String like this:

```
Gson g = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourClass>>(){}.getType();
List<YourClass> clazz = g.fromJson(yourString,type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to save and load List by Sharedprefernces:

```
public static final String NEWS = "news";
 private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

public void saveNews(List<ResponseNews> news) {
    mPreferences.edit().putString(NEWS, new Gson().toJson(news)).commit();
}

public List<ResponseNews> loadNews() {
    return new Gson().fromJson(mPreferences.getString(NEWS, ""), new TypeToken<List<ResponseNews>>() {
    }.getType());
}
```